# How to conditional render a compnent in react + typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

### Update

Maybe the solution lies in the way that i declare the component:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

export const ChapterDescription: FunctionComponent<
    ChapterDescription
   > = (
   {
    description,
    name,
   }: ChapterDescription,
   ) => (
   <div>
     <h3>{name}</h3>
     <p>{description}</p>
   </div>
 );
```

When i was using only `reactjs` for my components, i could easily do a conditionally render of a component like so (check if `chapters` array has items and **Only** then render the component):

```
<OtherComponent/>    
    <div>
        {chapters.length > 0 && <ChapterDescription
            name={name}
            description={description}
        />}
    </div>
<OtherComponent2 />
```

When i try that in typescript is get the error:

```
Type 'false | Element' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2322)
```

[image]

Is it bad practise any more to have conditional rendering ? 
How do i handle that case ?

Comment: Normally it's perfectly fine for children to be false. What type definition does that parent component have for its props (I think the component is "LesserContentColumn")? It may be restricting the types more than it should

Answer (score 11):

Well it is not so obvious but **the fragments is the solution** for the conditional rendering in typescript **or** one of the solutions:

Now it does not complain:

```
<Acomponent />
 <>
   {chapters && chapters.length > 0 && (
     <ChapterDescription
       name={selectedChapter.name}
       description={selectedChapter.description}
     />
   )}
 </>
<AnotherComponent />
```

source: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using ternary operator instead, that way you either use the component or null:

```js
<OtherComponent/>    
    <div>
        {chapters.length > 0 ? <ChapterDescription
            name={name}
            description={description}
        /> : null}
    </div>
<OtherComponent2 />
```

Comment: now it says null | Element. The truth should be hiding in the way that i declare the component, i ll update my question. thanks.

Comment: does the error disappear if you remove these lines? I had situations where typescript was misidentifying the problem due to another problem in the class declaration